# Access Group Variables Values Based on the Dynamic String Returned

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have PythonScript@0 task in YAML file of the pipeline which is getting the email ID based on the Invidiual CI Requestor. & I have a secret variable value stored in the variable groups with the key of same email Id as CI Requestor.

VARIABLE GROUP:

key[myemail@email.com] = value["SECURETOKEN"]

```
# Getting the email ID of CI requestor
email = '$(Build.RequestedForEmail)'
group_variable = f"$({email})"
print(group_variable )
# Above variable is printing the value as "$(myemail@email.com)", which I do no expect.
```

I have tried all string concatenation methods to get the value. such as.

```
group_variable = f"$({email})"
group_variable = "$({})".format(email)
group_variable = "$({0})".format(email)
```

I want to get the value as "SECURETOKEN" instead of "$(myemail@email.com)". Any sort of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: whats `securetoken`? also a built-in variable exists for requestedfor: `Build.RequestedForEmail`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: secureToken is a variable value stored in a group variables & that value would be person's   PAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the value of a secret value from the API. It will always be empty. In order for the Python task to access the secret it *must* be passed in explicitly as an environment variable or an input parameter.

Comment: Hey There, Thanks for the reply. I don't want to get the value from API. I just want to fetch the value based on the dynamic email returned.

Comment: The way the order of interpretation of values happens, you can't do what you want. The python script can't request arbitrary secret values and you can't construct a variable reference *IN* your pythen script and have it evaluated by the agent. Once the agent passes the context to Python for interpretation, the script contents and its execution context are set.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, it might be easier to grant the built-in Pipelines Agent user the "Act on behalf of others" permission. That way you don't need user PATs at all. Having a giant array of access tokens is a security nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: Okay Thanks, I guess that sums up my requirements.